# Run a bash with php

Tags: php, bash

Hello I am trying to execute a bash from php file but it does not work...

Here is my php file :

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('bash test.sh');
?>
```

Where if with ls for instance it works perfect...
This is my bash file :

```
touch file.txt
```

Thank you for your help !

PS : I try to use pwd to see where I am and I am in the same directory that the location of my php file so I don't understand why it does not work !

Comment: Are you calling the php file from the browser? If so, does the web-server user (apache, www, etc.) have write privileges in that directory?

Comment: Take care to get the paths right. You are relying on the PATH variable to find the bash executable and on the process operating on the file system folder your file is located in. Is that _both_ really working? Have a try using absolute paths for both :-)

Comment: A general hint on this, since it appears you are making your very first steps with php: always monitor your http servers error log file when programming in a web environment. That is where you find helpful error messages.

Comment: Using full paths will save you a lot of headaches. E.g.,  `shell_exec('/path/to/bash /path/to/test.sh');` and `touch /path/to/file.txt`